# Keep categorical data at median alongside continuous data for model prediction

Tags: r, predict, broom

I am trying to create a series of variable-based predictions from a model, based upon this post https://aosmith.rbind.io/2018/01/31/added-variable-plots I would like to use a model which has both continuous variables, categorical variables and a random effect.

This is the model I would like to use:

```
glmer(presence~1+diel+moonlightS+yeardayS+sstS+temperatureS+tide+(1|code), data=y2, family = binomial(link=logit))
```

Presence is either 0/1, Diel is either day or night, moonlight is proportion of lunar illumination, and tide is one of four tidal states (categorical).

However, part of the code I am using to keep data at the median for the predictions does not allow for categorical data to be entered into the model, and I would like to know how I could include this.

Firstly I scaled and centred continuous data:

```
data$temperatureS<- as.numeric(scale(data$temperature, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE))
data$sstS<- as.numeric(scale(data$sst, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE))
data$depthS<- as.numeric(scale(data$depth, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE))
data$moonlightS<- as.numeric(scale(data$moonlight, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE))
data$yeardayS<- as.numeric(scale(data$yearday, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE))
```

Next the model:

```
fit1 = glmer(presence~1+moonlight+depth+temperature+tide+diel+yearday+sst+(1|code) , data=data, family=binomial(link=logit))
```

Vector of variable names:

```
( mod_vars = all.vars( formula(fit1) )[-1] )
```

Function for prediction:

```
preddat_fun = function(data, allvars, var) {
  sums = summarise_at(data,
                      vars( one_of(allvars), -one_of(var) ), 
                      median) 
  cbind( select_at(data, var), sums)
}
```

Using the function to predict:

```
 pred_dats = mod_vars %>%
      set_names() %>%
      map( ~preddat_fun(y2, mod_vars, .x) )
```

After this section I get an error saying numeric data is required. I'm unsure how I can incorporate this into the function above.

Prediction:

```
preds = pred_dats %>%
  map(~augment(fit1, newdata = .x) ) %>%
  map(~mutate(.x, 
              lower = exp(.fitted - 2*.se.fit),
              upper = exp(.fitted + 2*.se.fit),
              pred = exp(.fitted) ) )
```

Data:

```
structure(list(depth = c(49.5, 49.5, 102, 39.5, 43, 15, 39.5, 
43, 44.5, 39.5, 139, 44.5), temperature = c(26.2, 25.3, 24.2, 
26.5, 23.2, 26.5, 26.5, 24.2, 26.5, 26.9, 26.2, 29.5), sst = c(27.54999924, 
28.54999924, 28.54999924, 25.54999924, 28.54999924, 28.54999924, 
28.54999924, 28.54999924, 28.54999924, 29.54999924, 28.54999924, 
28.54999924), diel = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Day", "Night"), class = "factor"), 
    tide = structure(c(2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
    2L, 2L), .Label = c("Ebb", "Falling", "Flood", "Rising"), class = "factor"), 
    yearday = c(79L, 79L, 79L, 81L, 79L, 79L, 84L, 79L, 79L, 
    91L, 79L, 103L), presence = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), moonlight = c(0.046850507, 0.946850507, 
    0.046850507, 0.946850507, 0.046850507, 0.046850507, 0.946850507, 
    0.946850507, 0.046850507, 0.046850507, 0.946850507, 0.046850507
    ), code = c(54921L, 54921L, 19505L, 54921L, 54921L, 44223L, 
    54921L, 54921L, 54921L, 44223L, 54921L, 54921L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Comment: I'd say with categorical variables it does not make sense to use the median. You could either look at the reference level or stratify the plot by combinations of the categorical variables, as you only have 2 here.

Comment: @kath Thank you! Do you know how I could edit the code to look at the reference level?

Comment: Substitue `median` with `~ ifelse(is.factor(.), levels(.)[1] , median(.))`. I'm not sure however that I can recommend, looking only at the references level.

Comment: @kath Thanks! I realised I left out the actual prediction piece of code- I've just added it in. Your advice solves my immediate issue but then I'm unable to find the standard error for the categorical data I think, I get this error `Error: object '.se.fit' not found`